# Android :: Connection Refused When Calling local host Web service Using SOAP

Tags: android, android-webview, processmaker

I am trying to connect my application to localhost(process maker like wamp server) web service(I am using my system ip address 192.168.2.xxx) but it says connection refused...

My log cat error:

```
06-03 11:43:49.250: E/ActivityThread(606): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d096d8 that was originally bound here
06-03 11:43:49.250: E/ActivityThread(606):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-03 11:43:49.250: E/ActivityThread(606):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-03 11:43:49.250: E/ActivityThread(606):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-03 11:43:49.250: E/ActivityThread(606):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-03 11:43:49.250: E/ActivityThread(606):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-03 11:43:49.250: E/ActivityThread(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-03 11:43:49.250: E/ActivityThread(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-03 11:43:49.250: E/ActivityThread(606):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-03 11:43:49.250: E/ActivityThread(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-03 11:43:49.250: E/ActivityThread(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-03 11:43:49.250: E/ActivityThread(606):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-03 11:43:49.250: E/ActivityThread(606):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-03 11:43:49.250: E/ActivityThread(606):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-03 11:43:49.250: E/ActivityThread(606):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-03 11:43:49.250: E/ActivityThread(606):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606): null
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d096d8 that was originally bound here
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-03 11:43:49.280: E/StrictMode(606):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d09a80 that was originally bound here
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d09a80 that was originally bound here
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-03 11:43:49.366: E/ActivityThread(606):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606): null
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d09a80 that was originally bound here
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-03 11:43:49.412: E/StrictMode(606):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-03 11:43:59.810: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-03 11:44:03.470: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-03 11:44:09.570: E/JavaBinder(722): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
06-03 11:44:09.570: E/JavaBinder(722): java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException
06-03 11:44:09.570: E/JavaBinder(722):  at android.os.Parcel.writeException(Parcel.java:1326)
06-03 11:44:09.570: E/JavaBinder(722):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:354)
06-03 11:44:09.570: E/JavaBinder(722):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-03 11:44:09.570: E/JavaBinder(722): Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
06-03 11:44:09.570: E/JavaBinder(722):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
06-03 11:44:09.570: E/JavaBinder(722):  at android.content.IIntentReceiver$Stub$Proxy.performReceive(IIntentReceiver.java:124)
06-03 11:44:09.570: E/JavaBinder(722):  at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.scheduleRegisteredReceiver(ActivityThread.java:809)
06-03 11:44:09.570: E/JavaBinder(722):  at android.app.ApplicationThreadNative.onTransact(ApplicationThreadNative.java:383)
06-03 11:44:09.570: E/JavaBinder(722):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a localhost from your device than use the 10.0.2.2 instead of  localhost.

Because your Android emulator is running on a Virtual Machine(QEMU) and you can not connect to a server directly running on your PC.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i am not using localhost i am using my system IP address.

Comment: also i am using above ip address it also says connection refused

Comment: 10.0.0.2 is also give connection refused

Answer (score 0):

If you run your application from Emulator, do as @Segi said, use 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost

If you run your application using real device, make sure that your device and PC is on the same network. then check your PC's Firewall, there's a high possibility that firewall blocks your app from accessing your computer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i am not using localhost i am using my system IP address.

Comment: also i am using above ip address it also says connection refused

Comment: Have you check your Firewall on your PC? try turning it off. and Check whether your manifest has the required permission.

Comment: can you tell me what are all the permission required.

Comment: You have to add this line:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> `

outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: i turned off the firewall now also connection refused.

Comment: Please post the logcat on your question, that would be very helpful :)

Comment: I don't think turning your firewall off is a good suggestion.